# Как решить ошибку "message": "TypeError: is undefined",

Tags: javascript

Как можно универсально решить проблему к обращению к ключам объекта?

Чтобы возвращало значение ключа, либо во всех остальных случаях false, и вне зависимости что туда передавать, главное чтобы не было никогда ошибки в консоли.

```js
let obj = {
  key: 'test', 
  key2: {
    subkey: 'subtest'
  }
};
let obj3 = false;

console.log(obj.key3.subkey);
console.log(obj2.key);
console.log(obj3.key5.subkey4);

function checkObj(obj){
 //
}

console.log( checkObj(obj.key3.subkey) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно попробовать решить хотя бы частично конструкцией `.?`

```js
let obj = {
  key: 'test', 
  key2: {
    subkey: 'subtest'
  },
};

let obj3 = false;

console.log(obj?.key3?.subkey);
console.log(obj?.key2?.subkey);
console.log(obj?.key2?.subkey?.name);
console.log(obj?.key);
console.log(obj3?.key5?.subkey4);
```

Comment: Спасибо, похоже то что нужно, что то мимо меня прошла такая конструкция, на undefined уже будет проще сделать проверку

Comment: А как правильно прописать такую конструкцию для вида `obj['key2']['subkey']` ?

Comment: вот тут сразу не скажу, можно в лоб: `value = obj['key2'] ? obj['key2']['subkey'] : undefined`

Comment: Эта конструкция называет optional chaining. Для `obj['key2']['subkey']` это будет `obj?.['key2']?.['subkey']`. Это же применимо и к массивам. Например `arr?.[0]?.[3]`